# Using an ArrayList with JOptionPane.showInputDialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm currently having the situation that I need to provide the user of my application a dialog with a number of options to choose from. 
Example:

```
Object[] possibilities = {"ham", "spam", "yam"};
String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    frame,
                    "Complete the sentence:\n"
                    + "\"Green eggs and...\"",
                    "Customized Dialog",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                    icon,
                    possibilities,
                    "ham");
```

It seemed that JOptionPane.showInputDialog could do this. However it seems that it can only use an array of Objects for the options to choose from, but in my case the list is not static, so I can't define an array, since I have an ArrayList with a variable size. The second point is that it doesn't give me the selected index back when I call it, but I neeed this since I have another complex list in the background that contains the values defined by the index of the option that was selected.
Is it somehow possible to push a dynamic list to this dialog or is there any other, more elegant and flexible way of doing what I need?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Construct your own JDialog with a JComboBox.  That way, you have control over the JComboBox with a ComboBoxModel.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was thinking about that too with a JFrame or something like that, but I didn't know that I can customize the JDialog in that way. So with a JComboBox I will be able to provide a dynamic list of elements?

Comment: Yes.  I recommend using a ComboBoxModel.  The DefaultComboBoxModel would probably work.

Comment: OK thanks, but when I do my own Dialog, I'm not sure how to react on the according actions by clicking the buttons. Do I have to define some additional listener for these buttons?

Comment: See the Oracle tutorial in mKorbel's answer.  Try, and when you get stuck, ask another Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `indexOf()` on your `List` to determine the index based on what `JOptionPane` returns.  The example below demonstrates this and could be expanded to work with a larger list of options.

```
List<String> optionList = new ArrayList<String>();
optionList.add("Ham");
optionList.add("Eggs");
optionList.add("Bacon");
Object[] options = optionList.toArray();
Object value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                                           "Favorite Food", 
                                           "Food", 
                                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
                                            null,
                                            options, 
                                            options[0]);

int index = optionList.indexOf(value);
```

Comment: That's actually what I was searching for in the first place, so I will award this the answered flag, although the other options are also good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- `Object[] possibilities = {"ham", "spam", "yam"};` should be `Items` for `JComboBox`
- [for similair issue to see Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/DialogDemoProject/src/components/CustomDialog.java) about [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input)